# Nontrivial objects with no nontrivial proper subobjects

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology

Are there any interesting examples of nontrivial objects with no nontrivial proper subobjects?

$\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ satisfies this property as a group, ring and field; do any other groups, rings or fields? How about categories? Are there any topological spaces satisfying some property that isn't inherited by any of its nontrivial subspaces? Cases of infinite cardinality would be especially interesting to me.

Any examples are appreciated, and if someone could make this question CW that would be excellent.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$; the one element semigroup (if you allow the empty semigroup). Two element lattice.

Comment: *do any other groups, rings or fields?* All simple abelian groups... all fields.. all division rings... all simple modules.  This sort of thing is pretty common in algebra.  I can't think of anything from topology, though.

Comment: @rschwieb The one-point space if you allow the empty space, and any of the three two-point spaces if you don't.

Comment: Is CW supposed to mean something?

Comment: @WilliamElliot Surely you have spent enough time on this site to be aware of "community wiki"?

Comment: @rschwieb I’m not sure I understand your comment; there are obviously fields with nontrivial subfields like $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$.  In what sense do all fields satisfy the above requirement?

Comment: @AlecRhea Sorry, I was in the frame of mind of substructures being ideals. But yeah, if just subfields, I should say something like prime order fields.

Comment: @rschwieb Ah, understandable, but I am just looking for subfields/subgroups etc. In particular, any infinite cardinality examples would be great.

Comment: @AlecRhea: $\mathbb{Q}$ is a prime field: any field of characteristic $0$ contains $\mathbb{Q}$, so any subfield of $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{Q}$ itself. Because every field contains its prime field (either $\mathbb{Q}$ of $\mathbb{F}_p$), those are the only examples for fields.

Comment: P.S. you really want “no nontrivial proper subobjects” (unless to you “nontrivial” implies “proper”, in which case you may want to say so, though it is implied by your comments).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Very cool, thanks for the comment. That is what I meant by nontrivial, but I'll edit for clarity.